# Mongoose Schema for remote MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I have opened a connection to my remote mongodb ec2 instance but now am trying to retrieve data that is nested within a collection. The database has multiple collections (ie visitor, campaign, form, etc...) and has data already in it from another source. I am using node + express for the application.

**1)** Do I have to define a schema in my app to match the remote database or can I just query for the data and store it in an object? 
[mongoose schema creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081611/mongoose-schema-creation/10083152#10083152)

**2)** Actually retrieving the values within the visitor collection, can I just use dot notation to query within the `visitor` collection for `visitor_id` using:

```
db.find(visitor.visitor_id)
```

Here is the database connection code I am using if that helps

```
var uri = 'mongodb://xx.xxx.xx.x'
var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true } };
  db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR connecting to: remote' + uri + '. ' + err);
} else {
    console.log('Successfully connected to: remote' + uri);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using mongoose, then yes, you need to define a schema in your app to match the database.
2. That notation won't work. If I understand the specific query you're trying to make (to fetch the document matching a `visitor_id`) then you'll need something roughly like this:

   ```
   // Assuming you already have mongoose connected to the database elsewhere
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
   var visitorSchema = new Schema({
       visitor_id: Number,
       etc: etc // the rest of your schema
   });
   var Visitor = mongoose.model('Visitor', visitorSchema);

   Visitor.findOne({ visitor_id: the_id_you_want_to_query }, function (err, doc) {
       // doc contains the visitor document, if found
   });
   ```

I suggest you familiarize yourself with queries with MongoDB and mongoose in particular—the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) aren't super easy to understand but cover most of the main cases.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, that helped clarify some things. How would it change if I wanted to query the whole db and only return those that had a a visit_id != null(most are null, while others have a unique id).

Comment: Querying for non-nulls is a bit messy. One way to do it is with the `$type` operator--this page should help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls