# How to put json object in database automatically?

Tags: json, node.js, database, nosql

I have a very large Json object that i want to put in a nosql database.
I would like to know:

- first, how to generate the database schema based on that Json object?
- second, is there a way to put this object automatically in the database, without manually specifying which value (in json object) goes in which column (in the database)?

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified which NoSQL database you're using in particular, for convenience, I'll assume you're using MongoDB when I talk about things that are implementation specific.

First off, you should know that NoSQL databases by nature are "schema-less". You still could implement your own schema (in your app, not the db), but that's optional, and mostly done just for validation purposes or to let future developers understand the planned structure of your data better. Read the Dynamic Schemas section in [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained) to know more. [Here is a SO answer explaining how you would do that in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081611/mongoose-schema-creation) and [here is the official guide/doc for it.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Second, NoSQL databases don't work in terms of columns or rows. Rather, you need to think in terms of collections and documents. So to answer your question : Yes, when you have a JSON object, you shove it in directly (before applying any required formatting if you've implemented a schema like in above). You don't enter data value by value (unless you've intentionally set it up to do so).

It sounds to me that you need to strengthen your fundamental understanding of how NoSQL works as you seem to be confusing yourself with concepts that belong to other DBMS. [Here is a neat slideshow to get you started](http://www.slideshare.net/drumwurzel/intro-to-mongodb) and [the previous article I linked you to](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained) also gives you a decent introduction.
After you're done, consider installing MongoDB or something similar and just playing around with the command line interface to get a good hang of it.

Comment: Thank you so mush for your priceless reply! That's what I did actually: no need for a schema since mongodb is schema-less and I can store my json object as it is and query it later since mongodb is a JSON-type storage engine. Thanks again.

Comment: What to do to avoid the collection being truncated, since the json object is very large?

Comment: No problem. Looks like you're getting the hang of MongoDB already.

As far as I know, if you're storing your json object as it is (i.e without applying any filters or so), then your object will not be truncated.

According to [this article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/), Mongo has a maximum document size of 16MB so unless your document is absurdly large, I think you'll be fine.