# Why does Mongoose requires schema when Mongodb itself doesn't have a schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I want to create a products table which has information about all the household appliances like refrigerator, Air cooler, Television e.t.c. I have created schema something like this.

```
var productSchema = mongooseDB.Schema({
    Brand: {type: String, required: true},
    categoryId: Number,
    Color: String,
    Type: String,
    Price: Number,
    Size: Number
});
```

But the problem is each product has different attributes. So i cannot think of any generic schema. How would I go with this ? Or should I create a seperate table for each specific product ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to set the option [`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) to `false` when defining your schema. You should probably have some common field to identify what kind of product it is. Also take a look at [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) -- might be useful.

Take heed however to the note: *do not set to false unless you have good reason*.

In terms of why mongoose uses schemas, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083152/1022914) explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not forced to use *Mongoose* at all if it doesn't fill your needs.
You can just use the [native *MongoDB* driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/) in your app.

Or I guess you can use *Mongoose* with an empty schema and specify the `strict` option to `false`.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Answer (score 0):

You can use discriminators to get polymorphic behaviour in mongoose. Check out my answer to this question:
[How to use mongoose schema when you have dynamic values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195449/how-to-use-mongoose-schema-when-you-have-dynamic-values/45198795#45198795)